# draw svg polygon in HTML with a list of holes

Tags: html, web, svg, polygon

I have a polygon with a list of holes (also polygons) within it. I want to draw it, preferably using `<svg><polygon .../></svg>`, the problem is that the shape is quite complicated, non-convex and using the `fill-rule` it creates a bad result.

for example with this code:

```
<html><body>

<!-- This is way I want it to look, where the red is a hole  -->
<svg height="210" width="500">
  <polygon points="0,0 50,30 100,0 50,100" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1;fill-rule:evenodd;"/>
  <polygon points="70,30 70,25 75,25 75,30" style="fill:red;stroke:blue"/>
</svg>

<!-- This is way it actually looks  -->
<svg height="210" width="500">
  <polygon points="0,0 50,30 100,0 50,100 0,0 70,30 70,25 75,25 75,30" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1;fill-rule:evenodd;"/>
</svg>


</body></html>
```

This is the result:

[image]

When removing the stroke it looks even worse

Comment: Use a path instead, then you can insert M or m commands to pick up the pen.

Comment: Try using this path instead; ` <path d="M0,0 L50,30 100,0 50,100z M70,30 L75,30 75,25 70,25 70,30z"/>`

Comment: Write you answer using `path` as an answer so I can mark it?